# Random Variate inside a function causing the function to behave unexpectedly

Tags: function-construction, random

I define a Random Variable drawn from a custom probability density.

```
u[xi_, yi_, zi_, τ_, δt_, θ0_, k_] := 
 RandomVariate[ProbabilityDistribution[(Sqrt[δt/τ]*(Cosh[(u*δt)/τ] +
(zi*Cos[θ0] + Sin[θ0]*(xi*Cos[k*δt] + yi*Sin[k*δt]))*Sinh[(u*δt)/τ]))/
(E^(((1 + u^2)*δt)/(2*τ))*Sqrt[2*Pi]), {u, -Infinity, Infinity}]]
```

I want to use this random variable inside the delayed function xfun:

```
xfun[xi_, yi_, zi_, θ0_, k_, δt_, τ_] := (xi - xi*Cos[2*θ0] - 4*Cos[2*k*Pi*δt]*Sin[θ0] + 
  2*xi*Cos[4*k*Pi*δt]*Sin[θ0]^2 + 2*yi*Sin[4*k*Pi*δt]*Sin[θ0]^2 +
  4*E^((2*δt*u[xi, yi, zi, τ, δt, θ0, k])/τ)*Cos[2*k*Pi*δt]*Sin[θ0]*
  (1 + zi*Cos[θ0] + xi*Cos[2*k*Pi*δt]*Sin[θ0] + yi*Sin[2*k*Pi*δt]*Sin[θ0]) +
  2*zi*Cos[2*k*Pi*δt]*Sin[2*θ0] + 2*E^((δt*u[xi, yi, zi, τ, δt, θ0, k])/τ)* 
  (3*xi + xi*Cos[2*θ0] - 2*(xi*Cos[4*k*Pi*δt] + yi*Sin[4*k*Pi*δt])*
  Sin[θ0]^2 - 2*zi*Cos[2*k*Pi*δt]*Sin[2*θ0]))/(-4*(-1 + zi*Cos[θ0] + 
  xi*Cos[2*k*Pi*δt]*Sin[θ0] + yi*Sin[2*k*Pi*δt]*Sin[θ0]) +
  4*E^((2*δt*u[xi, yi, zi, τ, δt, θ0, k])/τ)*(1 + zi*Cos[θ0] + 
  xi*Cos[2*k*Pi*δt]*Sin[θ0] + yi*Sin[2*k*Pi*δt]*Sin[θ0]))
```

Now checking the special case (specified by the arguments of xfun) I find that I will sometimes get values greater than 1 for my function

```
xfun[1, 0, 0, Pi/2, 1, 0.01, 1]
```

This should be impossible since I can check, replacing the function u[,,,,] with the symbol u in the RHS of the function xfun, that the maximum value xfun should take for any u in this special case should be 1.

```
Maximize[(xi - xi*Cos[2*θ0] - 4*Cos[2*k*Pi*δt]*Sin[θ0] +
 2*xi*Cos[4*k*Pi*δt]*Sin[θ0]^2 + 
  2*yi*Sin[4*k*Pi*δt]*Sin[θ0]^2 + 4*E^((2*δt*u)/τ)*Cos[2*k*Pi*δt]*Sin[θ0]*
  (1 + zi*Cos[θ0] + xi*Cos[2*k*Pi*δt]*Sin[θ0] + yi*Sin[2*k*Pi*δt]*Sin[θ0]) + 
  2*zi*Cos[2*k*Pi*δt]*Sin[2*θ0] + 2*E^((δt*u)/τ)*(3*xi + xi*Cos[2*θ0] - 
  2*(xi*Cos[4*k*Pi*δt] + yi*Sin[4*k*Pi*δt])*Sin[θ0]^2 -  2*zi*Cos[2*k*Pi*δt]*Sin[2*θ0]))/
  (-4*(-1 + zi*Cos[θ0] + xi*Cos[2*k*Pi*δt]*Sin[θ0] +  yi*Sin[2*k*Pi*δt]*Sin[θ0]) +    
  4*E^((2*δt*u)/τ)*(1 + zi*Cos[θ0] + xi*Cos[2*k*Pi*δt]*Sin[θ0] + 
  yi*Sin[2*k*Pi*δt]*Sin[θ0])) /. {θ0 -> Pi/2, k -> 1, δt -> 0.01, τ -> 1, 
   xi -> 1, yi -> 0, zi -> 0}, u]
```

Does anybody know what the source of the problem could be? Is there something about the behavior of the RandomVariate function that I am not understanding? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the definition of `xfun` you called `u` three times. Each time generated a different random variable. Use `Module` to structure `xfun` to call `u` only once and use that value all three times.

```
Clear["Global`*"]

u[xi_, yi_, zi_, τ_, δt_, θ0_, k_] := 
 RandomVariate[
  ProbabilityDistribution[(Sqrt[δt/τ]*(Cosh[(u*δt)/τ] \
+ (zi*Cos[θ0] + 
           Sin[θ0]*(xi*Cos[k*δt] + yi*Sin[k*δt]))*
         Sinh[(u*δt)/τ]))/(E^(((1 + u^2)*δt)/(2*τ))*
      Sqrt[2*Pi]), {u, -Infinity, Infinity}]]
```

Modified definition of `xfun`

```
xfun[xi_, yi_, zi_, θ0_, k_, δt_, τ_] := 
 Module[{urv = u[xi, yi, zi, τ, δt, θ0, k]},
  (xi - xi*Cos[2*θ0] - 4*Cos[2*k*Pi*δt]*Sin[θ0] + 
     2*xi*Cos[4*k*Pi*δt]*Sin[θ0]^2 + 
     2*yi*Sin[4*k*Pi*δt]*Sin[θ0]^2 + 
     4*E^((2*δt*urv)/τ)*Cos[2*k*Pi*δt]*
      Sin[θ0]*(1 + zi*Cos[θ0] + 
        xi*Cos[2*k*Pi*δt]*Sin[θ0] + 
        yi*Sin[2*k*Pi*δt]*Sin[θ0]) + 
     2*zi*Cos[2*k*Pi*δt]*Sin[2*θ0] + 
     2*E^((δt*urv)/τ)*(3*xi + xi*Cos[2*θ0] - 
        2*(xi*Cos[4*k*Pi*δt] + yi*Sin[4*k*Pi*δt])*
         Sin[θ0]^2 - 
        2*zi*Cos[2*k*Pi*δt]*Sin[2*θ0]))/(-4*(-1 + 
        zi*Cos[θ0] + xi*Cos[2*k*Pi*δt]*Sin[θ0] + 
        yi*Sin[2*k*Pi*δt]*Sin[θ0]) + 
     4*E^((2*δt*urv)/τ)*(1 + zi*Cos[θ0] + 
        xi*Cos[2*k*Pi*δt]*Sin[θ0] + 
        yi*Sin[2*k*Pi*δt]*Sin[θ0]))]
```

Testing,

```
SeedRandom[1234];

Max@Table[xfun[1, 0, 0, Pi/2, 1, 0.01, 1], {50}]

(* 1. *)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer but just an observation.  Occasionally there are errors such as the following (with just a slight modification of your function `u`):

```
u2[xi_, yi_, zi_, τ_, δt_, θ0_, k_, n_] := 
 RandomVariate[ProbabilityDistribution[(Sqrt[δt/τ]*(Cosh[(u*δt)/τ] + 
 (zi*Cos[θ0] + Sin[θ0]*(xi*Cos[k*δt] + yi*Sin[k*δt]))*
         Sinh[(u*δt)/τ]))/(E^(((1 + u^2)*δt)/(2*τ))*Sqrt[2*Pi]), {u, -Infinity, Infinity}], n]

x = u2[1, 0, 0, 1, 0.01, π/2, 1, 1000000];
```

[image: Error messages]